# Execute symfony task command from the shell_exec() permission denied

Tags: php, shell, symfony1, permission-denied

I have symfony task call "doNothing"  and i want to execute it from executing `shell_exec('/var/www/esm/symfony php symfony doNothing');`

by calling to my symfony action

apache error saying permission denied.

i think `www-data` user dont have permission how could i resolved this?

Edited

```
error is
```

sh: /var/www/esm/symfony: permission denied

Comment: Check the permissions of the `symfony` file in your symfony root (`/var/www/esm`)

Comment: its has -rwxrwxrwx permission

Comment: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/esm/symfony 
 i give still no luck

Comment: i checkd the apache error log found sh: /var/www/esm/symfony: permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look in the directory where your script is.

Use `ls -la` to show all files in the folder and their permissions (to execute php script file must have at least `x` bit assigned to www-data or its group).

Also all the parent directories up to `/` MUST have `x` bit assigned to user/group for apache to be able to change directory to.

Look. You have Tree structured Files system:

- `/var/www` is in `/var`
- `/var/www/esm` is in `/var/www`
- `/var/www/esm/symfony` is in `/var/www/esm`

So www-data user should have the ability to Execute (`x` bit) all of that directories.

So when in `/` execute `ls -l` and look wheter `/var` has `x` bit for www-data user or it's group (drw`x`rw`x`---) and it owns this directory. When in `/var` execute `ls -l` an so on...

You can change permissions to 777 for every directory. But DO NOT use `-R` key. Just change permissions to the directory only.

Comment: i gave sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/esm/symfony 
 permission still no luck

Comment: i checkd the apache error log found sh: /var/www/esm/symfony: permission denied

Comment: chown is not enough. check if all the files are readable, writeable and executable. To be shure you can run sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/esm/symfony. But after fixing the problem for security reasons unused permissions shuld be removed.

Comment: due to your apache log www-data can't access directory /var/www/esm/symfony. It means it can't EXECUTE this directory (or some of the parent directories). check x bit

Comment: check Ececute bits to all the parent directories. Maybe apache can't simply change directory to /var

Comment: im sorry i  cant undetstand what should i do to make  /var/www/esm/symfony executable

Comment: chown -R www-data:www-data  /var/www/esm/symfony tried but no luck

Comment: I gave permission as u said nu luck :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3095/discussion-between-webbandit-and-roshan)

Comment: solved the problem for me! I'm using php-fpm and running it from an nginx server. just chmod 777 all directories up to your script!